# Error while installing 32 bit Library on 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

```
$ sudo apt-get install package-name:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package package-name:i386
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.14.3) but 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6 is to be installed
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this error is not due to the installation of the ia32-libs package, but it is a problem that has arisen before. Does the error also occur when you try to install any other package?

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If it does not fix it, edit your question with the new info.

Comment: Happy to here that! Could you mark my answer as accepted then? I'm sad and tired to be unable to up-vote posts.

Comment: ok i have marked!!!